# URLs with % signs in them in bibtex files: how to get correct links after compiling with biber/biblatex

Tags: biblatex, urls

I have a bibtex file entry with a URL field:

```
url = {{https://links.jstor.org/sici?sici=0025-570X\%28198912\%2962\%3A5\%3C291\%3AHRATQS\%3E2.0.CO\%3B2-8}}
```

where I have manually escaped each percent sign with a backslash.

It compiles correctly with biblatex/biber but the resulting hyperlink in the document still has the escaped percentage sign and does not link correctly to the website.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Why not use https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689481 or https://doi.org/10.2307/2689481 instead?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to escape the `%`, the `url` field is printed verbatim, so there won't be a problem. Hence, just remove the backslashes before the percentage signs.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. I will check before I ask in future :-)

Comment: @chandra: You should *also* remove the second pair of braces at the start/end of the URL field. These braces would also be printed verbatim, resulting in a non-functional link with the `hyperref` package.

Comment: Thanks, @lockstep. I did not realize it, but I had removed the extra brace pair when I got it working.

Comment: I just want to add that for my configuration (LyX / MiKTeX 2.9) I do have to escape the URL. The citation style is based on "annotation.bst". I guess there are customisations in there, that are not compliant. So just in case anyone else has problems in that area: it is not neccessarily the case that urls are printed verbatim.

Comment: @Mene This question was for `biblatex`/`biber`, where my answer applies, AFAIK. You are using `bibtex` which is a completely separate system for dealing with bibliographies.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize... still confused about the different flavors of Tex and the eco-system around it. Thanks for the rectification!